# Is it possible to see why a symbol is required in C++

Tags: c++

I have a `C++` plugin for `R` which uses a shared library which is also used for other executables. Unfortunately I can't link all dependencies, as I need to link with `fpic`, and not all libraries are available this way.

This generally works fine, but now I have a piece of code, which, when enabled, causes the library to fail to load, due to an unresolved symbol. Unfortunately I can't work out why that piece of code pulls in that symbol.

So is there a way to see what requires the symbol? Maybe something akin to a stack trace?

My aim would be to amend the code base so that the missing symbol isn't required any more.

This is with gcc.

Comment: Not sure to understand your problem but maybe Dependency Walker may help you ?

Comment: and your platform is ... ?

Comment: If you know the symbol just search the entire project in the IDE or use `grep` form the command line.

Comment: I think you need something like verbose mode during dynamic load. Check if something like environment variable LD_DEBUG as described in http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html can help you

Comment: objdump can tell you everything you never wanted to know about object files

Comment: You may also employ the use of readelf and c++filt